# DAX Rank Formula

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, rank

I asked a similar question before of creating a DAX formula to sum rates for ranking purposes as seen by the 'Rank' column in the chart below ([DAX Sum of Average to Rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577436/dax-sum-of-average-to-rank)). However, instead of summing rates I need to rank the calculated measure from highest to lowest over time.

[image]

Since the Goal is 80%, person F and H should be above person E and G. The ideal order would be A, B, C, D, F, H, E, G after sorting. This is in a pivot table so calculated columns cannot be created due to OLAP limitations, so DAX formulas are preferred. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why the excel tag then?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is your DAX to create the Rank. You may like to use something like below:

```
rate:=IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( DimDate[CalendarMonthName]),
    [Avg],
    CALCULATE ( SUMX (FactTable, [amount] ) )
)

Rank:=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([rate])),RANKX(ALLSELECTED(DimTable[bank]),
        [rate],,,Dense), BLANK())
```

The rate is similar to what @TJ_ provided in your other thread but it is a calculated field instead of column and it sums [amount] to be used in Rank otherwise it use your default average calculation.

You might not need ALLSELECTED. It is used to consider the values selected only by the slicers. Please see screen and post your DAX for the Rank if it is not helpful.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The Rank formula works except when I sort by 'Total Rank' column, it ranks people with blank values higher than those who actually have values. Do you know how to change it so those with blank values are ranked lower?

Comment: Yeah I used the formula you gave with IF(NOT(ISBLANK[rate])).. etc. but it still ranks people with blanks higher than those with rates..

Comment: Please post the DAX you are using and sample data if possible.

Comment: The formula I'm using is Rank:=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Rate])),RANKX(ALLSELECTED([Name]),[Rate],,,Dense),BLANK()). I can't attach images in a comment, but the rank doesn't distinguish between people with a couple blanks (like if Jan and Apr is blank but the other months have values) and those without (have values for all months), it seems to rank based on value only.

Comment: Not sure how your data is laid out. If there is blank for a month and even if we use just RANKX(ALLSELECTED(DimBank[bank]),[rate],,,Dense) (omitting ISBLANK check) 
the rank should be proper (all blank month will have same low rank then the month with value).